# Which functions are used from a unit

Tags: delphi

I have a huge project that I have started more than ten years ago .
I used a unit that I have created for define many function, converting dates,  and so on .
Compiling this project I get hundreds of hints and warnings almost all of them are in this Unit file.
I think I  use only a few of this functions after project changes in last years.
Then It is better to exclude this unit file from project and copy used functions in a new unit.
I decided to comment out this unit name in USES section and find out which functions are used but it is so hard because project has about 150 forms!
also there are hundreds of function in this unit and I can not use "search for usage" for every function

Any Solution?

Comment: Why not use "Find in Files"?

Comment: Use some code coverage tool.

Comment: @JerryDodge I know which units are using this unit (more than 100 files!)I want to know which functions from this unit are used.
 Try more than 200 function name one by one in "Find in files"?
if there in no tool, the only possible way is this...

Comment: Exactly, what I mean, for each function, do a global search for those function names. Boom, a list of every single time it's used, even if it's commented out. That's the quick and easy way, without resorting to third-party tools.

Comment: Fix the warnings and hints.

Comment: Yes , But doing this form more than 200 function ...oops...search for usage also is a possible solution. but it is really so hard for this count of functions.:(

Comment: @LURD many of this function are useless now and there is exactly 1393 hints and 630 warnings.

Comment: Then there is not such tool!

Comment: Remove the unit from all uses, compile and add it back where it does not compile - you can write a small cmd program or batch script that does that - you're a programmer after all ;)

Comment: @StefanGlienke sure there are some tricks to do that and all are time consuming .I was just asking if there is a tool . if not I must do it hard way!;)

Comment: You want to know **code coverage**. Search for such tool.

Comment: Compile with debug info on. Look at the unit. Code that is linked (used) in your code will have a blue dot in the gutter that indicates a breakpoint can be set on that line. If no lines between `begin` and `end;` in a method or function have the blue dot, it is not being linked into your app. And for future reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says very clearly you cannot ask for a tool or software library (component) recommendation here. And @LURD has the right solution - fix the hints and warnings. You only have to do it once.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: I'd comment out everything in the interface section of that unit. The compiler will tell which symbols are unknown, unless they can be found in other units too and were hidden by this one.

Comment: I think [Peganza Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/products_pal.html) can do this. There is a "Lite" version - I don't if this feature is stripped there.

Comment: I did It Hard way, It took two days. 
I think I Must create a tool For this !
Thanks to everybody for answers

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest leaving the old unit in the project and `uses` clauses, and simply mark it with the `deprecated` [hinting directive](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Hinting_Directives), eg:

MyUnit.pas

```
unit MyUnit deprecated;
...
end.
```

That way, the compiler will warn you about any units that `uses` this unit, and will warn about any specific symbols that are being referenced from this unit. Then you will know exactly which symbols to copy to your new unit.

Once you have resolved all of the warnings, you can then remove the `deprecated` unit from your project.

Comment: It will, unfortunately, **not** warn about any symbols used from this unit (just tried that, in 10.2.2 Tokyo). It will only warn that the unit is deprecated. So that won't find the used symbols, I'm afraid.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis then that is a regression that Embarcadero needs to fix, as it works in earlier versions, and is against the [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Hinting_Directives) : "***When a hint directive appears in a unit declaration, it means that the hint applies to everything in the unit**. For example, the Windows 3.1 style OleAuto.pas unit on Windows is completely deprecated. Any reference to that unit **or any symbol in that unit** produces a deprecation message.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. I tried this(berlin 10.1) but unfortunately  only warning message is unit deprecated. no info about symbols...

Comment: I just tried it in XE2, and sure enough, it doesn't warn on accessing a symbol in a `deprecated` unit, unless the symbol itself is marked as `deprecated` too.  I could have sworn that worked fine before.

Comment: Might I suggest that this misleading and inaccurate answer be removed in that case